# What are the options available to restrict the Internal HTTP(S)Load Balancer(ILB), which would allow traffic only from allowed IPs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking, gcp-load-balancer

We have two shared VPC projects, one for non-prod ("**svpc-projectA**")and other one for prod ("**svpc-projectB**"). In non-prod we have service project called **projectA**, which is using network from "**svpc-projectA**". In prod we have service project called **projectB**, which is using network from "**svpc-projectB**". GKE is running in both service projects and ingress is configured with ILB. Also each service project contain jump servers.

Now services running in PROD is accessible via Jump server in non-prod project and vice-versa.

Traffic Flow is as below,

Jump Server (projectA) -> ILB (projectB) -> gke (projectB)

Jump Server (projectB) -> ILB (projectA) -> gke (projectA)

Tried Below options

1. ***In (**projectA**) Jump Server -> (**projectB**) GKE flow***, I setup Egress with deny firewall rule in **svpc-projectA**, Destination filters value as **projectB** full subnet. Which is working, but there are other departments as well, so I can't add Egress on their VPC. So I need to restrict it from our end. Requirement is based on the request I should whitelist IPs.
2. ***In (**projectA**) Jump Server -> (**projectB**) GKE flow***, I tried creating Ingress rule with Deny in **svpc-projectB** with Targets - Target tags of GKE cluster(**projectB**) and Source filters as **projectA** full subnet. But it is not working.

We want to allow traffic only from whitelisted IPs, so as part of that First I want to strict traffic from non prod to prod, then traffic from other department vpcs.

All SVPCs are connected to common project called connectivity hub via HA VPN. Same way other department VPCs are connected to same connectivity hub project.

Comment: What do you want to achieve/restrict?

Comment: Do you have some type of peering setup between your two VPCs?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere : I have updated the question. Basically I want to restrict ILB traffic from non-prod vpc to prod vpc.

Comment: @GariSingh : There is no peering between SVPCs, but all SVPCs are connected to common project called "connectivity hub" via HA VPN. Which has routes to all other VPCs

Comment: Is it HTTPS or TCP/UDP internal load balancer? And do you have specific IP ranges for your Prod Namespace and your Non-Prod namespace on GKE?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere: As I mentioed in the subject, it is a HTTP(S) Internal Loadbalancer. Yes, we have separate subnet ranges(ip ranges) allocated for non prod and prod.

Comment: Cloud Armor seems compliant only for external load balancer and therefore not applicable for you. I think the most relevant is to create a firewall deny policy on your non prod IP ranges to access your prod load balancer.

Comment: I tried FW options already, but FW can't block ILB traffic.